# R. Карты Шухарта

Tags: r

Присутствует ли в R пакет для обработки данных по контрольным картам Шухарта или уже готовый алгоритм / функция?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В CRAN репозитории представлены 2 пакета для построения контрольных карт:

- [qicharts](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=qccqicharts)
- [qcc](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=qcc)

Более подробную информацию об использовании пакетов можно получить в документации и виньетках, включённых в состав пакетов.

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно!!!